# databricks POST call to execute a notebook with parameters

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

In my notebook I have declared parameters and through the Jobs UI I am able to successfully execute the notebook by passing the default and different parameters. Now I am trying to run the notebook through a POST call. I wanted to know how to pass the notebook parameters?

On Postman this is what I tried but none of them worked,
https://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out. I passed the parameters in the body when testing through Postman and as JSON payload when using Python requests.